# How to call a table function in jpa

Tags: java, jpa, netbeans, nativequery

I have been trying to call a function that i created using jpa but i keep getting this error

(org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: 'udf_searchEmployeeLeaves' is not a recognized built-in function name.
Error Code: 195)

```
public List<EmployeeLeaves> searchEmployeeLeaves(String str) throws EmployeeLeavesException {

    try {
        Query query = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT udf_searchEmployeeLeaves(?1) FROM LAB ");

        query.setParameter(1, str);

        return query.getResultList();

    } catch (Exception e) {

        throw new EmployeeLeavesException("[searchEmployeeLeaves-ERROR]: " + e.getMessage());

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the call is incorrect.

You have to call the table function like this:

```
Query query = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM udf_searchEmployeeLeaves(?1)");
```

Comment: I'm happy to held :-)